# Colorbar Ticks Mathtext Format

Tags: matplotlib, plot, format, colorbar

The title is self explanatory, could not find how to implement it. For the axis ticks format similar command looks like this: `ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)`, there is no problem with this one, it works. But for the colorbar's ticks to make them appear in the MathText format I could not find how to implement it. I have tried to pass the `useMathText=True` as an arg into the `cbar.ax.tick_params()` and `cbar = plt.colorbar()` but that did not work.

to recreate:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

p = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0.5, 0.5]])
e = np.array([[0, 1, 4], [3, 0, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4]])
t = mtri.Triangulation(p[:, 0], p[:, 1], e)
z = np.random.rand(5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
ax.set(xlim=(min(p[:, 0]), max(p[:, 0])), ylim=(min(p[:, 1]), max(p[:, 1])))
c = ax.tricontourf(t, z, 10, cmap='plasma', vmin=np.min(z), vmax=np.max(z),
                   levels=np.linspace(np.min(z), np.max(z), 100))
ax.triplot(t, color='white', lw=0.1)
ax.set_title('Title', fontsize=16)
cbar = plt.colorbar(c, cax=cax, format='%.0e', ticks=np.linspace(np.min(z), np.max(z), 3))
cbar.set_label('Colorbar title', fontsize=16)
# cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)
ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC yes, a bunch of attribute errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the comments by Ernest, the colorbar for a contour gets a `FixedFormatter`, which doesn't accept `useMathText`. In my version, the code didn't give an error, but as you pointed out, also didn't generate the desired output.

So, the answer is to change the formatter to a ScalarFormatter, and at the same time tell it to use math text. The formatter for a vertical colorbar can be set via `cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter`.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

plt.tricontourf(np.random.uniform(1, 10, 100), np.random.uniform(1, 10, 100), np.random.uniform(1e-6, 1e-5, 100))
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Please let me know whether it now works for you. (My system, now with matplotlib 3.2.1, Pycharm 2019.3.4 under Windows.)

Comment: Checked the version. Ive tried your example and it worked. The difference with my case is that I use `ax.tricontourf()` to plot the data and `cbar = plt.colorbar()` is similar, but then `cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)` causes errors in my case. I will post a piece of my code.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but surely answering a question with a question is pretty bad style. I guess it just tells you that the question isn't clear enough and just should not be ansered at all. Concerning the actual problem, consider that `ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)` only works for formatters that have a `useMathText` attribute; and contour colorbars use a fixed formatter by default.

Comment: The downvote is from me. The reason is that after trying your code in both 3.1.2 and 3.2.0 I get the exception: `AttributeError: 'FixedFormatter' object has no attribute 'set_useMathText'` from the line `axis.major.formatter.set_useMathText(useMathText)` in `.../matplotlib/axes/_base.py`. And a message `AttributeError: This method only works with the ScalarFormatter` traced back to `cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)`, presumably for the reason outlined in Ernest's comment. I'm of the opinion that "can't reproduce" answers are useful, but only when all the details (OS,etc) are included

Comment: If you were to update your answer to include how you are executing that piece of code and your OS so it is more useful in determining why exactly it works for you but not the OP and myself I'd definitely consider removing my downvote.

Comment: I have uploaded a piece of code to reproduce. All packages are last versions. Python 3.8.2. Uncommenting `cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)` gives an error described by @WilliamMiller

Comment: @JohanC now as you changed your example to plt.tricontourf(), I cannot run it with `cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(useMathText=True)` without an error. I have tried matplotlib 3.2.0 and 3.2.1.

Comment: @JohanC But in this your example it does not seem to me that mathtext is working, it should show numbers in format like 10^-5 instead of 1e-5.

Comment: Yes it is, and it appears to be genuinely using mathtext in the formatting. This would be the correct answer I believe, nicely done