# change formatting ticks of colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'd like to change the colorbar ticks format of some plots I'm generating.

[image]

The result I'm looking for is the one achieved in here for a contour plot ([Matplotlib Colorbar Ticks Mathtext Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894584/matplotlib-colorbar-ticks-mathtext-format))

This is a MWE to see my problem:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import axes_grid1
from matplotlib import colors, ticker
import numpy as np

def add_colorbar(im, aspect=15, pad_fraction=0.5, **kwargs):
    """Add a vertical color bar to an image plot."""
    divider = axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(im.axes)
    width = axes_grid1.axes_size.AxesY(im.axes, aspect=1./aspect)
    pad = axes_grid1.axes_size.Fraction(pad_fraction, width)
    current_ax = plt.gca()
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size=width, pad=pad)
    plt.sca(current_ax)
    cbar = im.axes.figure.colorbar(im, cax=cax, **kwargs)
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=True))
    cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0, 0))
    return cbar

im = plt.imshow(np.random.uniform(8000, 12000, (10,10)), norm=colors.LogNorm(),cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
cbar = add_colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC, yes, I've tried. The result is the same I already have. That's why I said that the result I was looking for is the same as the one in the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ticklabel_format(..., scilimits=(m, n)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.ticklabel_format.html) can be used to force a scientific format for powers of 10 outside the range between m and n. With `(0,0)` scientific format will always be used.

If you are using a lognorm, the colorbar gets both major and minor ticks especially to show log formatting. You can change their format and their position to standard ticks first, as follows:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import axes_grid1
from matplotlib import ticker
from matplotlib import colors
import numpy as np

def add_colorbar(im, aspect=15, pad_fraction=0.5, **kwargs):
    """Add a vertical color bar to an image plot."""
    divider = axes_grid1.make_axes_locatable(im.axes)
    width = axes_grid1.axes_size.AxesY(im.axes, aspect=1./aspect)
    pad = axes_grid1.axes_size.Fraction(pad_fraction, width)
    current_ax = plt.gca()
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size=width, pad=pad)
    plt.sca(current_ax)
    cbar = im.axes.figure.colorbar(im, cax=cax, **kwargs)
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.AutoLocator())
    cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=True))
    cbar.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.ScalarFormatter())
    cbar.ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', scilimits=(0, 0))
    return cbar

im = plt.imshow(np.random.uniform(8000, 12000, (10,10)), norm=colors.LogNorm())
cbar = add_colorbar(im)

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]